# Vert.x event bus consumer called twice

Tags: vert.x, sockjs, event-bus, vertx-eventbus

i wrote a simple code for communicate between a java server in vert.x and a browser client with the event bus library. The client send a message to the server through the event bus and the server call eventbus.consumer to read the message and reply to it.
I notice something strange, idk why the consumer method is called twice, I aspect it call one. How can i solve this? Thanks.
This is my code:

SERVER

```
 SockJSBridgeOptions options = new SockJSBridgeOptions().
      addInboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddressRegex("out"));

    sockJSHandler.bridge(options);

    router.route("/eventbus/*").handler(sockJSHandler);

    eventBus.<String>consumer("out", event -> {
      logger.info(event.body());
      event.reply("TEST");
    });

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(serverPort, res -> {
      if (res.succeeded()) {
        startPromise.complete();
      } else {
        startPromise.fail(res.cause());
      }
    });
```

CLIENT

```
  var eb = new EventBus('http://localhost:8088/eventbus');
  eb.onopen = () => {    
    eb.send('out', {name: 'tim', age: 5817}, (e, m) => {
      console.log("TEST RESPONSE")
      console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
    });
   }
```

CONSOLE SERVER OUTPUT

```
apr 07, 2022 7:55:43 PM it.unibo.guessthesong.lobby.LobbyVerticle
INFO: {"name":"tim","age":5817}
apr 07, 2022 7:55:43 PM it.unibo.guessthesong.lobby.LobbyVerticle
INFO: {"name":"tim","age":5817}
```

CONSOLE CLIENT OUTPUT

```
TEST RESPONSE
{"type":"rec","address":"92888ada-fada-43ff-9677-9eeed95b44da","body":"TEST"}
TEST RESPONSE
{"type":"rec","address":"2ced1214-13cf-4ebf-b7d8-6773612097e7","body":"TEST"}
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but the message is sent once every time. Is Client code maybe wrapped in some method that is invoked twice? Try putting a console.log before `eb.send` to rule that out.

Comment: It's worth checking how the verticles are deployed and how messages are passed to the eventBus. Via send? or publish? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56717905/4177271

Comment: I opened an issue on github with more details but nobody answer me.
https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/4329